# Python: extract dictionary in list into new row

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have below dictionary in list in Python, and I would like to extract the value of "detail" and split it to new columns. I have the dictionary store in the dataframe as per below:

```
id_x = ['1','2','3','4']
phone = ['45651','5465652','35453','09434']
detail = [[{'qty':'10', 'name':'indeed','code':'AAA'}],
          [{'qty':'10', 'name':'indeed','code':'AAA'}, {'qty':'50', 'name':'erd','code':'BBB'}],
          [{'qty':'13', 'name':'oilen','code':'CCC'}],
          []
         ]

df= pd.DataFrame({'id':id_x, 'phone':phone, 'detail':detail})
df

id  phone   detail
1   45651   [{'qty': '10', 'name': 'indeed', 'code': 'AAA'}]
2   5465652 [{'qty': '10', 'name': 'indeed', 'code': 'AAA', {'qty':'50', 'name':'erd','code':'BBB'}]
3   35453   [{'qty': '13', 'name': 'oilen', 'code': 'CCC'}]
4   09434   []
```

I expect to get column: id, phone, detail_qty, detail_name, detail_code

and it will extract to a new row when has more than 1 element.

Here is expected dataframe:

```
id  phone   detail_qty  detail_name detail_code
1   45651   10          indeed      AAA
2   5465652 10          indeed      AAA
2   5465652 50          erd         BBB
3   35453   13          oilen       CCC
4   09434
```

Could you please advise how to get the desired list?

Thanks.

Comment: Please have a look at [How to ask a good
question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Basically, you should
attempt to solve your problem, post your code, and ask a specific question
about it.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new dataframe `df2`

This(condition) `if len(df.loc[i,'detail']) > 0` checks if the list is empty and `for` loop to check if there are more than 1 dictionary in each list in `detail` column

I hope remaining is self explanatory

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame()
count = 0
for i in df.index: 
    id_temp = df.loc[i,'id']
    phone_temp = df.loc[i,'phone']
    if len(df.loc[i,'detail']) > 0: 
        for j in df.loc[i,'detail']:
            df2.loc[count,'id'] = id_temp
            df2.loc[count,'phone'] = phone_temp
            df2.loc[count, 'detail_qty'] = j['qty']
            df2.loc[count, 'detail_name'] = j['name']
            df2.loc[count, 'detail_code'] = j['code']
            count += 1
    else: 
        df2.loc[count,'id'] = id_temp
        df2.loc[count,'phone'] = phone_temp
        df2.loc[count, 'detail_qty'] = ''
        df2.loc[count, 'detail_name'] = ''
        df2.loc[count, 'detail_code'] = ''
        count += 1

print(df2)
```

**Output**

```
  id    phone detail_qty detail_name detail_code
0  1    45651         10      indeed         AAA
1  2  5465652         10      indeed         AAA
2  2  5465652         50         erd         BBB
3  3    35453         13       oilen         CCC
4  4    09434
```

Comment: Hopefully the answer is helpful. If your question is solved, please **accept** the solution.